# Pointer overwritten after end of the function

Tags: c++, qt

I have this function:

```
QLinkedList<hTag>::iterator *lookForLastHTag(hTags tag, QLinkedList<hTag> openedTags){
    QLinkedList<hTag>::iterator *i = new QLinkedList<hTag>::iterator();
    *i = openedTags.end();
    while(*i != openedTags.begin()){
        *i-=1;
        if ((*(*i)).tag == tag)
            return i;

    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

written with the QT framework. It searches backwards through a singly linked list of `hTag`, a specific tag in an enumeration called `hTags` (please note that the former one is a struct and the second one is an enum class).

The `hTag` struct is defined this way:

```
struct hTag{
    hTags tag;
    int hierarchy;
};
```

whereas the hTags enum class just defines some tags.

The problem is that, after the function returns the `i` pointer, it gets weirdly overwritten by other data. I don't understand that since I've allocated space dynamically in the heap for that iterator *just to avoid this problem*. I don't understand why the content of the pointer `i` (not the thing it points to, the 32-bit number inside `i`) is returned correctly (in the sense that the 32-bit number inside the pointer is correctly copied outside the function). However, the content of `i` (the pointee) isn't. Just after the end of the function, it gets overwritten with junk **even if it's declared on the heap and *shouldn't* be influenced by the end of the function**.

Could you please help me sorting that problem out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why is there a `new` in your code? Or even more surprisingly, why do you have pointers to iterators?? You are returning a pointer to a iterator to a list that lives in the scope of the function. That pointer is garbage outside of the function (adding more `*` wont help)

Comment: maybe the missing hint is: `openedTags` is not on the heap but on the stack and gets destroyed when the mehtod returns

Comment: First get rid of pointers to iterator and decrement it like `--it;` instead.

Comment: Following @tobi303 The problem then is not the pointer per se (although unusual), but passing the list not as (const) reference...

Comment: Additionally, this kind of design offers greate opportunity for memory leaks - deleting the iterator object after not being needed any more is easily forgotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is passing the list by value:

```
QLinkedList<hTag>::iterator *lookForLastHTag(hTags tag, QLinkedList<hTag> openedTags)
//                                                                      ^^
```

This results in a copy of the list being created, which is destroyed again as soon as control flow returns from the function.

The iterator instance you return then refers a list that does not exist any more, if you use it, you end in undefined behaviour.

To avoid this, you need to pass your list as either reference or pointer, preferrably a const one (as you do not modify it; however, you need to return a const_iterator then, too):

```
QLinkedList<hTag>::const_iterator* lookForLastHTag(hTags tag, QLinkedList<hTag> const& openedTags)
//                 ^                                                            ^    ^(!!!)
```

Then your iterator object will point to the original list as being passed to the function and you are fine with this first point.

Additionally, you implemented a memory leak: If no element is found, the iterator remains unused, so you must delete it again before returning:

```
delete i;
return nullptr;
```

Still, there is some non-negligible risk a user creating further memory leaks by forgetting to delete the returned pointer when not needed any more, especially, as this is a *very* unusual way to use iterators (sure, not your responsibility any more, but you can avoid this right from the start by better design):

```
QLinkedList<hTag>::const_iterator lookForLastHTag(hTags tag, QLinkedList<hTag> const& openedTags)
//                               ^ (no pointer!)
{
    QLinkedList<hTag>::const_iterator i = openTags.end();
    while(i != openTags.begin())
    {
         --i;
         if(i->tag == tag)
             return i;
    }
    return openTags.end();
}
```

As side effect, the code got less complicated, won't you agree?

Side note: you might want to have a look at [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead; no need for re-inventing the wheel...